# Disable trailing whitespace lint warnings for Markdown file

Tags: filetype-markdown, plugin-ale

I use vim 8 and ALE plugin. On a markdown page, I see the following from `ALEInfo`

```
 Current Filetype: markdown
Available Linters: ['alex', 'languagetool', 'markdownlint', 'mdl', 'proselint', 'redpen', 'remark_lint', 'textlint', 'vale', 'writegood']
   Linter Aliases:
'remark_lint' -> ['remark-lint']
'writegood' -> ['write-good']
  Enabled Linters: ['alex', 'languagetool', 'markdownlint', 'mdl', 'proselint', 'redpen', 'remark_lint', 'textlint', 'vale', 'writegood']
 Suggested Fixers:
  'prettier' - Apply prettier to a file.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'textlint' - Fix text files with textlint --fix
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
```

My markdown file has certain lines that have trailing whitespace - they're legitimate as a  way to prevent markdown rendering from collapsing the newlines.

How can I disable the warnings about trailing whitespace on these lines?

Comment: You'd want to find out which linter gives the warning and configure it appropriately.

Comment: How can I find the specific linter for that warning?

Comment: one way would be to check the linters docs; another would be to run each one and see what the results are.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your coc-settings.json file and implement these changes. It fixed the whitespace related issues for me.

```
"markdownlint.config": {
    "default": true,
    "whitespace": false
  },
```

Source:

1. [Markdown Lint Rules from GitHub Repo](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/master/doc/Rules.md#md025)
2. [Marus's Blog Talking about Linting Markdown Syntax](https://mkaz.blog/code/linting-markdown-syntax/)

Screenshot: Notice how there are no warnings from my linter and indentation is maintained.

[image: Working on my machine.]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think OP is using ALE, not coc.

Comment: In available linters markdownlint was mentioned in OP's post and personally I was getting a lot of annoying warnings from markdownlint as well, that was the only reason I wrote for markdownlint. Thanks for letting me know about ALE being used.